# Is the word "Wissenschaft" broader than "science"?

Tags: word-usage, single-word-request, scientific-language

In my German class we were asked to deliver a little "Vortrag über ein wissenschaftliches Thema". I was surprised when more than the half of the students talked about themes which, in English, cannot precisely be deemed scientific. Does the word "Wissenschaft" posses a broader meaning than "science"?

Comment: In Deutschland gilt Theologie als Wissenschaft.

Comment: Note, that the English word *science* can also be used in a way that includes the humanities, social sciences and even theology.

Comment: @user unknown: Die Aussage finde ich zu pauschal. Natürlich ist in der persönlichen, unreflektierten Definition vieler (z. B.: Wissenschaft ist, was an Universitäten betrieben wird) Theologie enthalten und historisch wurde es auch jahrhundertelang allgemein als Wissenschaft angesehen, aber ich wage schon zu behaupten, dass es heute nur noch sehr wenige gibt, die sich einmal mit einer sinnvollen Abgrenzung des Begriffs *Wissenschaft* auseinandergesetzt haben, und Theologie weiterhin hinzuzählen – ausgenommen solche, die sie nur als Wissenschaft einstufen, um sie an Universitäten zu halten.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: In erster Linie sind mal die gewählten Landespolitiker, die diese Propaganda weiter alimentieren zu nennen. In Deutschland ist Theologie also ganz offiziell Wissenschaft. Ausnahme sind die, die das anrüchig finden.

Comment: @user unknown: Politiker entscheiden (zum Glück) nicht darüber, was man offiziell Wissenschaft nennen darf (oder generell über Begriffe), sondern höchstens, was an Hochschulen gelehrt wird (auch wenn das vielleicht einige als äquivalent ansehen). Es gibt überhaupt niemanden, der derartige Dinge offiziell festlegt.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Das ist richtig. Es ist nur die am ehesten offizielle Stelle.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you take the definition given in the english [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science)

> Science […] is a systematic enterprise that builds and organizes knowledge in the form of testable explanations and predictions about the universe.

then the word `science` can be directly translated to `Wissenschaft`.

If you take a smaller definition, also given in wikipedia

> It is often treated as synonymous with 'natural and physical science', and thus restricted to those branches of study that relate to the phenomena of the material universe and their laws, sometimes with implied exclusion of pure mathematics.

then the word `science` can be directly translated to `Naturwissenschaft`. (The inclusion of biology, medicine and its branches depends on the same interpretation in German and English.)

Comment: It’s all in the answer: The first definiton translates to *Wissenschaft,* the second to *Naturwissenschaft.*

Comment: @c.p. If you encounter the words in German, it's relatively clear, what is meant. If you want to use them for yourself, you have to ask *yourself* what you want to express exactly and then choose accordingly.

Comment: @c.p.: There are two different definitions provided in this answer for *science* in English. There is no ambiguity in German with *Wissenschaft*.

Answer (score 5):

Wissenschaft is certainly much broader than science because wissenschaft includes humanities disciplines like history, anthropology, literature studies, religious studies, translation studies and so on. Humanities tend to have a relativistic approach to knowledge (truth is always relative to context) whereas sciences tend to have a positivistic approach (absolute truth exists and can be discovered).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, *Wissenschaft* comprises the humanities as well as the sciences. There is no exact equivalent to the term *science* in German; *Wissenschaft* is subdivided into overlapping fields such as *Naturwissenschaften*, *Lebenswissenschaften*, *Gesellschaftswissenschaften*, *Geisteswissenschaften*.

Comment: Lebenswissenschaften are a subset of Naturwissenschaften. You just miss Mathematics and Informatics, which don't fall into any of these categories. The fields don't overlap, but single subjects fall into several fields.

Comment: Well, computer science is a branch of mathematics, which in turn is considered a _Geisteswissenschaft_ by some and a dedicated _Formalwissenschaft_ by others.

Comment: If you regard Mathematics as subjective, you can consider it a Geisteswissenschaft. If not, it's a field of itself, let's call it Formalwissenschaft.

Comment: @Toscho... not really important nit pick... how do Geistenwissenschaften and for example Sozialwissenschaften not overlap?

Comment: @Toscho: It's not about being subjective as such. One reasoning I have come across for considering mathematics a Geisteswissenschaft is that it does not describe anything that exists "naturally", it builds man-made models (not unlike classifying grammatical structures or categorizing stylistic figures).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper That's what I mean. If you regard mathematical objects as man-made models and as such subjective, yes, then it's Geisteswissenschaft. But if you regard mathematical relations as universal, human independant relations between mathematical (possibly man-made) objects that every human or other being can *discover*, then it's not a Geisteswissenschaft.